# What should I write in column of Member State of First Country when I am coming to Hungary from India

Tags: schengen-visas

What should I write in columun of Member State of First Country when I am coming to Hungary from India, for my study in Debrecen

Comment: Don't you mean "member state of first entry"?

Comment: @user112511 How are you travelling to Hungary and what countries will you pass through to get there?

Answer (score 1):

*Member state* refers to a state of the Schengen area. If it reads *Member state of first **entry***, then you fill in the first country of the Schengen area you enter (probably the one you'll fly to).